# RDP to Windows 7 is stuck on Welcome screen after wake-on-lan from sleep

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, sleep, wake-on-lan, hybrid-sleep

I am trying to set up wake-on-lan for my office desktop (Windows 7 Enterprise). I want it to sleep when I am not there, unless I wake it up remotely and use it in a remote desktop session. Things initially work ok out of the box (no changes in BIOS or network adapter): if the desktop sleeps, my RDP session wakes it up (it beeps), then I can enter my password. However at this moment the RDP session stays stuck on the welcome screen, forever:

[image: Welcome screen]

This happens both for reconnecting to existing sessions or for logging in as a new session. Things only get unstuck and the RDP session wakes up completely when I move the mouse (the desktop's own physical mouse , not the mouse on the remote client - I am testing this from a laptop in the same room, so I have physical access to the desktop). Any idea what I should do to make the desktop wake up completely even when I have no physical access to it?

Comment: If nothing helps and even Restart-Computer powershell cmdlet not works, you can try to restart the computer using WMI in powershell: Invoke-WmiMethod -ComputerName COMPUTER_IP -Credential (Get-Credential) -Class Win32_Process -Name Create -ArgumentList "shutdown -r -f -t 0" . BTW, Jessica's solution didn't help in my situation (IDK what really happened with my computer), but forced reboot solved the problem.

Comment: This may be related to the USB suspend state of your USB devices or hubs...

Answer (score 1):

Would connecting as the console session help?

```
mstsc /admin
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem for years. After a lot of research and experimentation, I created the following script and it works for me and some of my colleagues...

Put the following in a text file and name it as .bat (like Release_RD.bat)

`tasklist -s your_machine_name -fi "imagename eq mpnotify.exe"`

`set /p pid=Enter PID found above:`

`taskkill -s your_machine_name -pid %pid%`

`pause`

If you aren't currently looking at the spinning Welcome screen, attempt to log in again so that your remote desktop client is actively on the Welcome screen

Double-click the .bat script and follow the directions in it. You might have to run the script twice if there are multiple mpnotify.exe processes.

If it works, the hung remote session will then proceed past the Welcome screen and you'll be logged in.